# struct timer_list, timer doesn't stop

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a problem with the following code. 
Every time that I call ioctl REGISTER the timer starts, when it expires it calls "update" which schedules a task using work queue, doJob method simply update the timer with a new expiration.

When I call ioctl UNREGISTER the timer is killed... but it continues to call update (and thus to update its expiration). Why the timer doesn't stop after calling ioctl UNREGISTER?

```
int time = 1;
module_param(time, int, 0644);
int delay;
struct workqueue_struct* wq;
struct work_struct task;
struct timer_list timer;        /* timer */

long ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long args) {
    switch (cmd) {
        case REGISTER:
            add_timer(&timer);
            return 0;
        case UNREGISTER:
            del_timer_sync(&timer); 
            return 0;
    }
}

static void doJob(struct work_struct *work) {
    printk(KERN_EMERG "\ndoJob\n");
    mod_timer(&timer, jiffies + delay); 

}
void update(unsigned long arg) {
    queue_work(wq, &task);
}
struct file_operations fop = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .unlocked_ioctl = ioctl
};

static struct miscdevice dev = {
    .minor = MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    .name = "timer",
    .fops = &fop
};


static int __init init(void)
{
    delay = HZ * time / 1000; 
    if (delay < 1) {
        printk(KERN_EMERG "time param is too small\n");
        return -1;
    }

    init_timer(&timer);
    timer.data = 0;
    timer.function = update;
    timer.expires = jiffies + delay;

    if (misc_register(&dev) < 0) {
        printk(KERN_EMERG "error registering misc device\n");   
        return -1;  
    }
    wq = create_workqueue("timer_task");
    INIT_WORK(&task, doJob);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit fini(void)
{   

    misc_deregister(&dev);
    printk(KERN_EMERG "deregistered\n");

}

module_init(init);
module_exit(fini);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-del-timer-sync.html) for `del_timer_sync()` say this:

```
Callers must prevent restarting of the timer, otherwise this function is meaningless.
```

In other words, `del_timer_sync()` waits for the handler to exit, but if that handler reschedules the timer, then it'll happily run again next time.

All you need to do is maintain another variable `timer_active`.  Set it to true before starting the timer, and to false before deleting the timer.  Then only reschedule the timer when `timer_active` is true.  With that order, you're guaranteed that no more timers will run after `del_timer_sync()` returns.